# Angular Reactive Forms: Make Touched and Invalid form fields red

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to make the input box (and text area) of an angular reactive form have a red border, when the form controls are markedastouched and invalid. It used to work on previous versions of material (recently upgraded to material 15) and now it no longer works as expected. I want the user experience to be... when a user tries to click Submit on a form, if a form field is invalid, then make the border of the input red.

I've tried using:

```
.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
    border: 1px solid red; 
 }
```

but everything... including the hint on the bottom of the input box has a red border. I'd like the invalid status to make the border of the input field itself red instead.

EDIT: This is the behavior i want for the input [link](https://ibb.co/G9GMDz9)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only target input then you can use

```
::ng-deep .mdc-text-field--invalid:not(form){
  border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a good start... but is there anyway to avoid something like this ?? [link](https://ibb.co/K24z06P)

Comment: This is sort of what I'm looking for [link](https://ibb.co/G9GMDz9) ... this is how the previous version of material handled touched and invalid form controls that were inputs

Comment: Have you tried to override mat-label from your component?

Comment: yup.. but it didn't have the desired effect.